# could not resolve property: Date of: using DateTimeOffset (NHibernate 3.2.0.4000)

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I recently got an exception from NHibernate when trying to access the `Date` property of a `DateTimeOffset` property.

```
var v1 = nhSession.Query<MyType>.Where(o => o.DateTimeOffsetProperty.Date == DateTimeOffset.Now.Date).ToList();
```

I would have thought this would have "just worked."  What is the best solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an HQL generator that does the following in `BuildHql`:

```
return p_treeBuilder.MethodCall(
    "date"
  , new HqlExpression[] { (HqlExpression) p_visitor.Visit(p_expression) }
);
```

This seems to be working, but I'd like to know if this is already built in and I missed it.  Thanks!

Comment: From what I can see, only the properties of `DateTime` have been considered so far (`DateTimePropertiesHqlGenerator`). Please open a Jira issue to get that added for `DateTimeOffset`.